# Turning Camera On Takes Forever to load

Tags: python, opencv

When I press the button for the camera to load, it takes about 10 seconds. Why is that the case? Also, can I reduce that time? When I close the camera, its instantly. When I reopen the camera, it still takes a long time. I don't think it is a problem with my computer, but I think it is something about the efficiency of my code. Here is my code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from time import sleep
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageTk


white       = "#ffffff"
lightBlue2  = "#adc5ed"
font        = "Constantia", 30
WIDTH       = 1920
HEIGHT      = 1080
fontButtons = (font, 12)
maxWidth    = 1000
maxHeight   = 600
cam_on      = False
cap         = None
mainWindow = Tk()
mainWindow.title('RocketShip')
mainWindow.configure(width = WIDTH, height = HEIGHT, bg="black")
mainFrame = Frame(mainWindow)
mainFrame.place(relwidth = 0.6, relheight = 0.8, relx = 0.2, rely = 0)
cameraFrame = Frame(mainWindow, bg = "blue")
cameraFrame.place(relwidth = 0.2, relheight = 0.8, relx = 0, rely = 0)
micFrame = Frame(mainWindow, bg = "blue")
micFrame.place(relwidth = 0.2, relheight = 0.8, relx = 0.8, rely = 0)

lmain = Label(mainFrame)

def show_frame():

    if cam_on:

        ret, frame = cap.read()    

        if ret:
            HEIGHT = mainFrame.winfo_height() + 5
            WIDTH = mainFrame.winfo_width() + 5
            cv2image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)    
            img = Image.fromarray(cv2image).resize((WIDTH,HEIGHT))
            imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img)        
            vid_lbl.imgtk = imgtk    
            vid_lbl.configure(image=imgtk)    
        
        vid_lbl.after(10, show_frame)

def start_vid():
    global cam_on, cap
    stop_vid()
    cam_on = True
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0) 
    show_frame()

def stop_vid():
    global cam_on, cap
    cam_on = False
    
    if cap:
        cap.release()
        vid_lbl.config(image="")
        cap = None

vid_lbl = Label(mainFrame)
vid_lbl.grid(row=0, column=0)







#Buttons
TurnCameraOn = Button(cameraFrame, bg = "blue", command = start_vid, text = "Turn Camera On", font = font)
TurnCameraOn.place(relx = 0, rely = 0, relheight = 0.5, relwidth = 1)
TurnCameraOff = Button(cameraFrame, bg = "blue", command = stop_vid, text = "Turn Camera Off", font = font)
TurnCameraOff.place(relwidth = 1, relheight = 0.5,relx = 0, rely = 0.5)
muteButton = Button(micFrame, bg = "blue", text = "Mute Yourself", font = font)
muteButton.place(relx = 0, rely = 0, relheight = 0.5, relwidth = 1)
unmuteButton = Button(micFrame, bg = "blue", text = "Unmute Yourself", font = font)
unmuteButton.place(relx = 0, rely = 0.5, relheight = 0.5, relwidth = 1)

#file menu
menubar = Menu(mainWindow)
file = Menu(menubar, tearoff = 0)
menubar.add_cascade(label ='Commands', menu = file)
file.add_command(label ='Open Camera', command = start_vid)
file.add_separator()
file.add_command(label ='Exit', command = lambda:mainWindow.destroy())
mainWindow.config(menu = menubar)
mainWindow.mainloop()
```

Comment: Try adding `print` statements to test which line(s) of code take up most of those 10 seconds. That way we can be sure what is actually causing the problem. If it's the `cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)` line, then please remove the `tkinter` tag and wait for someone who knows more about `opencv` to answer the question. If it's caused by `tkinter`, I will try my best to help you.

Comment: move the `cap = cv2.VideoCapture()` out of that function, place it at start of code and in the stop vid function redefine it to that again and replace the `if` to `if cam_on:` an move `cam_on = False` to the end

Comment: @Matiiss That looks like a possible solution even though starting the program will now take 10 sec. If you write an answer, I will upvote it :D

Comment: ok, i just checked it. And it is indeed the ```cap = cv2.VideoCapture()```. I also deleted the tkinter tag

Comment: @PandaMan456_ Then try what @ Matiiss suggested: move the `cap = cv2.VideoCapture()` to the strat of your code and the `cap.release()` to the end of your code. That way you will only get the 10 seconds lag when you start the start the program.

Comment: I did some more research and found out that if you swap ```cap = cv2.VideoCapture()``` with ```cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)```, it runs a lot faster. Hope this helps anyone else with this problem if they need it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is an improved version. It basically means that the user doesn't have to wait long once the buttons are enabled, also it means that the user doesn't have to wait for the process to finish before the GUI becomes responsive. Basically run it and see for yourself (new `load_cap()` function and imported `threading`).

```py
import cv2
from tkinter import Tk, Frame, Button, Label, Menu
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageTk
from threading import Thread


white       = "#ffffff"
lightBlue2  = "#adc5ed"
font        = "Constantia", 30
WIDTH       = 1920
HEIGHT      = 1080
fontButtons = (font, 12)
maxWidth    = 1000
maxHeight   = 600
cam_on      = False
cap         = None
loaded_cap  = False
loading_cap = False

mainWindow = Tk()
mainWindow.title('RocketShip')
mainWindow.configure(width = WIDTH, height = HEIGHT, bg="black")
mainFrame = Frame(mainWindow)
mainFrame.place(relwidth = 0.6, relheight = 0.8, relx = 0.2, rely = 0)
cameraFrame = Frame(mainWindow, bg = "blue")
cameraFrame.place(relwidth = 0.2, relheight = 0.8, relx = 0, rely = 0)
micFrame = Frame(mainWindow, bg = "blue")
micFrame.place(relwidth = 0.2, relheight = 0.8, relx = 0.8, rely = 0)
lmain = Label(mainFrame)


def load_cap(init=False):
    TurnCameraOn.config(state='disabled')
    TurnCameraOff.config(state='disabled')
    global loading_cap, loaded_cap, cam_on

    def _load():
        global cap, loaded_cap, loading_cap
        loading_cap = True
        loaded_cap = False
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        loaded_cap = True
    if not loading_cap:
        Thread(target=_load).start()
    if not loaded_cap:
        mainWindow.after(100, load_cap)
    elif loaded_cap:
        loading_cap = False
        TurnCameraOn.config(state='normal')
        TurnCameraOff.config(state='normal')


def show_frame():
    if cam_on:
        ret, frame = cap.read()

        if ret:
            HEIGHT = mainFrame.winfo_height() + 5
            WIDTH = mainFrame.winfo_width() + 5
            cv2image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            img = Image.fromarray(cv2image).resize((WIDTH,HEIGHT))
            imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img)
            vid_lbl.imgtk = imgtk
            vid_lbl.configure(image=imgtk)

        vid_lbl.after(10, show_frame)


def start_vid():
    global cam_on
    cam_on = True
    show_frame()


def stop_vid():
    global cam_on, cap
    if cam_on:
        cap.release()
        vid_lbl.config(image="")
        load_cap()
    cam_on = False


vid_lbl = Label(mainFrame)
vid_lbl.grid(row=0, column=0)







#Buttons
TurnCameraOn = Button(cameraFrame, bg = "blue", command = start_vid, text = "Turn Camera On", font = font)
TurnCameraOn.place(relx = 0, rely = 0, relheight = 0.5, relwidth = 1)
TurnCameraOff = Button(cameraFrame, bg = "blue", command = stop_vid, text = "Turn Camera Off", font = font)
TurnCameraOff.place(relwidth = 1, relheight = 0.5,relx = 0, rely = 0.5)
muteButton = Button(micFrame, bg = "blue", text = "Mute Yourself", font = font)
muteButton.place(relx = 0, rely = 0, relheight = 0.5, relwidth = 1)
unmuteButton = Button(micFrame, bg = "blue", text = "Unmute Yourself", font = font)
unmuteButton.place(relx = 0, rely = 0.5, relheight = 0.5, relwidth = 1)

load_cap(init=True)
#file menu
menubar = Menu(mainWindow)
file = Menu(menubar, tearoff = 0)
menubar.add_cascade(label ='Commands', menu = file)
file.add_command(label ='Open Camera', command = start_vid)
file.add_separator()
file.add_command(label ='Exit', command = lambda:mainWindow.destroy())
mainWindow.config(menu = menubar)
mainWindow.mainloop()
```

It basically uses `threading` to load the `cap` in the "background" and also doesn't allow user to press buttons while it is loading, the thing is that it almost immediately starts when user presses the start video button and it immediately stops when user presses stop video button, you can also add what you mentioned in comments if that helps reduce time too. This script simply improves user experience IMO, not really that much performance improvement, but see for yourself.